# Any site for monitoring equatorial oceanic waves?

Tags: ocean, oceanography, waves, wave-modeling

I  use Carl Schreck's site [Equatorial Wave Zoo](https://ncics.org/portfolio/monitor/mjo/) for monitoring atmospheric waves such as Kelvin wave, Equatorial Rossby wave, filtered MJO OLR, Mixed Rossby Wave(MRG),etc. 
Here is an example - [Kelvin Wave OLR](https://pub.cicsnc.org/mjo/v2/map/cfs/olr/global/olr.cfs.kelvin.global.7.png)

In addition I use Matt Wheeler's BOM site(unavailable at the moment) for the same information.

Now I am getting interested in the ocean and it's characteristics as part of my effort in learning coupled models i.e. air - sea models.

Is there a site for monitoring equatorial oceanic waves(in real time with lag) such as oceanic Kelvin wave, Rossby wave etc ? That should help me in identifying along the equator at least where upwelling or downwelling is likely to occur.

I would prefer a site for my basin i.e. Indian Ocean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few sea surface height datasets available on [PO.DAAC](https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/) (the Physical Oceanography Distributed Active Archive Center), but this one seems to be (near-)real-time and global: the [SARAL Near-Real-Time Value-added Operational Geophysical Data Record Sea Surface Height Anomaly](https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/ALTIKA_SARAL_L2_OST_XOGDR?ids=SpatialCoverage&values=Global&search=wave).
It was launched in 2013 so there is just 3 years of data so far but it should help I think.

Similarly you have a few current datasets such as the [OSCAR 1 degree ocean surface currents](https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/OSCAR_L4_OC_1deg?ids=Measurement&values=Ocean%20Circulation) dataset which was launched in 1992.

These are all raw datasets though, so you'll have to do the data processing and the plotting yourself.

The altimetry data provides a good way of looking at waves. Apart from SARAL, [AVISO](http://www.aviso.altimetry.fr/en/data.html) provides high quality, remotely sensed, gridded and raw altimetry data.

Comment: I decided to edit your answer to add AVISO instead of posting it as a comment. I hope you don't mid.

Comment: @aretxabaleta Sure, no worries!